# Call to undefined method PDO::last_Insert_Id()

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm getting an error message: Call to undefined method PDO::last_Insert_Id()

Here's my code:

```
$testcode = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO tblCategory
                             (Category, DisplayOrder)
                             VALUES('Test', 0)");
try {
            $testcode ->execute();
            $ID = $conn->last_Insert_Id();
}

catch (PDOException $e) 
    {echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

var_dump($conn instance of PDO) returns bool(true) so $conn is the PDO connection.

How do I correct so I don't get the error? I do need that last inserted id. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This PDO method is called [`lastInsertId()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), not `last_Insert_Id()`.

So:

```
$ID = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. I can't believe I didn't catch that.